# Concat array multiple times based on value within the Array.

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to design a little schedule for recurring tasks at my workplace. In order to set this up I am looping through my data to find the value of "Quarterly" in column 2 and "Recurring" in column 3.

If it does find these values, I push the row data into an array. I then concat the array multiple times (for this I used a different function not shown in the code below) based on the 4th value in the array, named timesrecurring.

Lastly I copy the array onto another sheet using .setvalues(). The code is below:

```
function myFunction() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Input Table"); 
 var targetsheet = ss.getSheetByName("Summary Calendar");
 var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();
 var datarange = sheet.getRange(8, 2, lastrow-1 , 10).getValues();
 var x = [];

for(i=0; i<datarange.length; i++){

 if (datarange[i][1] == "Recurring" && datarange[i][2] == "Quarterly" ){

  x.push([datarange[i][0],datarange[i][1],datarange[i][2],datarange[i] 
  [3],datarange[i][4],datarange[i][7],datarange[i][8],datarange[i] 
  [9],datarange[i][5],datarange[i][6])


  var timesrecurring = datarange[i][3] 
  var y = replicateArray(x,timesrecurring)

  targetsheet.getRange(targetsheet.getLastRow()+1, 2, 
  y.length,y[0].length).setValues(y);
  }
 }

}
```

As you can see here I am looking for the rows with "Quarterly" and "Recurring" and push the relevant rows into the array. Then I concat the array based on the value of timesrecurring.

The script work well if there is only one line with "quarterly" and "recurring" in the original datarange on which I applied the for loop. However once I add a second line the following happens: [image]

There are supposed to be 6 rows with the first column FTE reporting and 3 rows with  Ad-hoc. However the script first copies FTE reporting from the original data 6 times and then it takes both FTE reporting and Ad-hoc 3 times (although it was only supposed to be 3x). It seems that the second time around that it stores both the line for FTE reporting and for Ad-hoc in the Array rather than just the Ad-hoc line.

I have tried a couple of things to get around this issue and looked online but I couldnt find anything that worked. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You grow `x` with each `x.push` call made. So if x has four different rows in it when called to be replicated, then you will have 8 in the result.

Probably you wanted to only add the specific `datarange` row to `x` multiple times. You can use `push.apply` syntax to avoid needing to type the inner elements of `datarange[i]`:

```
const x = [];
datarange.forEach(function (row, i) {
  if (row[1] === "Recurring" && row[2] === "Quarterly") {
    var timesRepl = row[3];
    for(var n = 0; n < timesRepl; ++n) {
      Array.prototype.push.apply(x, row);
    }
    ... // Do other stuff with a quarterly recurring row
  }
  ...// Do other stuff with any row
});
...
```